# Get DDL of all tables under schema in one database in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone tell me a query to DDL of all tables under schema in database.
I know how to get a DDL of a table.

```
select get_ddl('table', 'ods.users');
```

It gives us only one table DDL. But in my I have around 40 tables.
I want to get all tables DDL at a time instead of getting one by one. Is there any query available. If so please guide me.

Regards,
Kathija.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET_DDL can script entire schema(with all objects inside):

```
select get_ddl('SCHEMA', 'ods');

select get_ddl('SCHEMA', 'ods', true);  -- to get qualified names
```

---

With Snowflake Scripting block it is possible to list over tables/views/functions/... only:

```
DECLARE
CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME) AS name
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                 AND TABLE_SCHEMA ILIKE 'ODS';
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_view_defs(view_name TEXT, definition TEXT);

  FOR rec IN CUR DO   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REPLACE('INSERT INTO temp_view_defs(view_name, definition)
                        SELECT ''<view_name>'', GET_DDL(''TABLE'', ''<view_name>'')'
                        ,'<view_name>'
                        ,rec.name);
 END FOR;

 LET rs RESULTSET := (SELECT * FROM temp_view_defs);

 RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

For sample:

```
CREATE SCHEMA ODS;
CREATE TABLE ODS.TAB1(i INT);
CREATE TABLE ODS.TAB2(id INT DEFAULT 0) COMMENT = 'Test';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @lukasz, Thanks for your quick reply. It gives us SP's, tables etc. I need only tables DDL. is it possible to get only tables DDL

Comment: @kathija Definitely! It is possible to enumerate a specific type of objects

Comment: Thanks once again. <view_name> should be replaced with TABLE. I have executed the same query and it is failing as SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'END'.

Comment: @kathija it is only column alias it could be anything. Second please run the code using Snowsight instead of Classic UI - [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks Lukasz and it worked in Snowsight. May I know why it doesn't work in classic UI.

Comment: @kathija Please check the link from comment above: Using Snowflake Scripting in Classic Web Interface.